# how to convert a ASN1_object to readable format using openssl library .?

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509

X509_extension  structure have a variable of ASN1_object . i want to read what is the content in that  .
Can any one tell me how to do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An ASN1_OBJECT is just OpenSSL's representation of an OID, an object identifier. If you only want to know it's OID, then:

```
ASN1_OBJECT *obj = X509_EXTENSION_get_object(ex); // ex is your X509_EXTENSION *
char buff[1024];
OBJ_obj2txt(buff, 1024, obj, 0); // 0 means it will prefer a textual representation (if available) rather than the numerical one
```

Then buf will contain a C string with the OID.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data value of the object as int the code fragment below:

```
ASN1_OBJECT *obj = X509_EXTENSION_get_object(ex);
char *dt_value = (char *)ext->value->data
printf("Object Value: %s\n", dt_value);
```